# Copy List<Object> with "addAll" method NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, list, nosuchelementexception

I think I have a problem in my code, but I can't find why.
When I'm using chemin.next() its working fine.
But when I do `new_chemin.addAll(chemin.next());` I have a NoSuchElementException

```
 public Zone cherche_chemin(List<List<Zone>> chemins, List<Zone> zones_exclues, Zone zone_arrivee) {
    boolean new_way = false;
    for (Iterator<List<Zone>> chemin = chemins.iterator(); chemin.hasNext();) {
        List<Zone> zones = chemin.next().get(chemins.size() - 1).getVoisinsAccessible(zones_exclues);
        for (Zone test_zone : zones) {
            new_way = true;
            if (test_zone == zone_arrivee) {
                return chemin.next().get(1);
            } else {
                List<Zone> new_chemin = new ArrayList<>();
                enw_chemin.addAll(chemin.next());          // THIS LINE
                new_chemin.add(test_zone);
                chemins.add(new_chemin);
                zones_exclues.add(test_zone);
            }
        }
        chemin.remove();
    }
    if (new_way) {
        return cherche_chemin(chemins, zones_exclues, zone_arrivee);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `chemins`....not `chemin`

Comment: Change `enw_chemin.addAll(chemin.next());` to `new_chemin.addAll(chemin.next());`

Comment: @hagubear they don't use chemins after line 3, that's not the issue.

Comment: @Eran thanks but that was not the issue, it's a mistake in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note `iterator.next()` move to next element immediately. change to like this

> ```
> public Zone cherche_chemin(List<List<Zone>> chemins, List<Zone> zones_exclues, Zone zone_arrivee) {
>     boolean new_way = false;
>     for (Iterator<List<Zone>> chemin = chemins.iterator(); chemin.hasNext();) {
>         List<Zone> cheminList = chemin.next();
>         List<Zone> zones = cheminList .get(chemins.size() - 1).getVoisinsAccessible(zones_exclues);
>         for (Zone test_zone : zones) {
>             new_way = true;
>             if (test_zone == zone_arrivee) {
>                 return cheminList.get(1);
>             } else {
>                 List<Zone> new_chemin = new ArrayList<>();
>                 enw_chemin.addAll(cheminList);          // THIS LINE
>                 new_chemin.add(test_zone);
>                 chemins.add(new_chemin);
>                 zones_exclues.add(test_zone);
>             }
>         }
>         chemin.remove();
>     }
>     if (new_way) {
>         return cherche_chemin(chemins, zones_exclues, zone_arrivee);
>     } else {
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working ! But I got a new really weird problem ! I used the debug, and at the line `zones_exclues.add(test_zone);` it's adding correctly `test_zone` in `zones_exclues` but it also change the `chemins` by adding `test_zone` in the first list of `chemins`

Answer (score 0):

Please read on [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()).

Well your problem is

```
if (test_zone == zone_arrivee) {
            return chemin.next().get(1);
} else {
    List<Zone> new_chemin = new ArrayList<>();
    new_chemin.addAll(chemin.next());          // THIS LINE
    new_chemin.add(test_zone);
    chemins.add(new_chemin);
    zones_exclues.add(test_zone);
}
```

encapsulate it by : (Note your element is changing here)

```
if(chemin.hasNext()) {
    if (test_zone == zone_arrivee) {
                return chemin.next().get(1);
    } else {
        List<Zone> new_chemin = new ArrayList<>();
        enw_chemin.addAll(chemin.next());          // THIS LINE
        new_chemin.add(test_zone);
        chemins.add(new_chemin);
        zones_exclues.add(test_zone);
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the element same :

```
for (Iterator<List<Zone>> chemin = chemins.iterator(); chemin.hasNext();) {
    List<Zone> zoneList = chemin.next();
    for (Zone test_zone : zoneList.get(chemins.size() - 1).getVoisinsAccessible(zones_exclues)) {
        new_way = true;
        if (test_zone == zone_arrivee) {
            return zoneList.get(1);
        } else {
            List<Zone> new_chemin = new ArrayList<>();
            new_chemin.addAll(cheminList);          // THIS LINE
            new_chemin.add(test_zone);
            zoneList.add(new_chemin);
            zones_exclues.add(test_zone);
        }
    }
    chemin.remove();
}
```